# GraalVM native image does not support MBean server

Tags: java, vert.x, graalvm, graalvm-native-image

I want to convert the executable jar file to the native image via GraalVM.
I use the command:

```
native-image --initialize-at-build-time=com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer -jar target/resource-1.0-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

Then the process will be stopped with following exception:

```
Error: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.oracle.graal.pointsto.constraints.UnsupportedFeatureException: Detected a MBean server in the image heap. This is currently not supported, but could be changed in the future. Management beans are registered in many global caches that would need to be cleared and properly re-built at image build time. Class of disallowed object: com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer  To see how this object got instantiated use --trace-object-instantiation=com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer. The object was probably created by a class initializer and is reachable from a static field. You can request class initialization at image runtime by using the option --initialize-at-run-time=<class-name>. Or you can write your own initialization methods and call them explicitly from your main entry point.
Error: Use -H:+ReportExceptionStackTraces to print stacktrace of underlying exception
```

I use following dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
        <artifactId>vertx-web</artifactId>
        <version>${vertx}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
        <artifactId>vertx-web-client</artifactId>
        <version>${vertx}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.0-b180830.0359</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-secretmanager</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
        <artifactId>vertx-hazelcast</artifactId>
        <version>${vertx}</version>
    </dependency>
```

I guess some libraries are not supported. But how can I find out, which libraries.
So is there some tools ore commands to find out, which library I have to replace?
Or Im on the wrong way and the problem is not the library?

Comment: Read the error message. It explains how to find out what path is leading to this problem, and suggests a couple of solutions.

Comment: Hazelcast exposes JMX beans, so that's probably the library you're looking for. Maybe this how-to does also help: https://how-to.vertx.io/graal-native-image-howto/

Comment: @OliverMarienfeld Thank you, this helps a lot. So the Logging Framework log4j2 are not supported, so I will remove it.

Comment: unfortunately all the examples does not work. Because the use the old version of graalvm and if I use the old version, then OSX throw an exception application is defect. Does someone has an example code in Github who works?